# How can I see my unbuffed stats?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are certain times (like when levelling up and choosing which to invest in) I'd like to see what my Magicka/Health/Stamina are, unbuffed by any gear I might be wearing. Short of removing all gear before doing this, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around the UI for a bit, I can conclude that there is currently no way of doing this in a straight-forward manner.

Comment: Sadly, this is the same conclusion I've reached. By going under "Active Effects" I can at least see what's buffing me and by how much and subtract in my head, but I have to remember to do this each time before I level up, since there's no way to cancel the perk selection screen.

Answer (score 3):

Just add all your gear to your favorites, but don't assign any number to them.

This way, you can easily go through your favorites menu and remove the check on everything. When you are done you can toggle everything on again. This should be an easier way than going through the whole item menu system...